# How to make indicator / How to process C++ "annotated" line comments

Tags: c++, antlr, antlr4

I am newble in antlr and till now I know how to parse the source file and access to visitor and listener.
I want to make indicator in the source file ex. //@start and //@end and I want to access to this indicator by using listener, but the issue I faced is that the comments are skipped through lexer rule for line comments in .g4 (I used grammar file c++ in the github ).
How can I create a parser rule not affect on other rules found in the grammar file?
I need to use the ctx for this indicator for wrtiing before or replace ,, this is my target
below code explain the source file.

```
 for(int i=1;i<=c;i++)
{
    fact=fact*i;
    //@start ...this is indicator 1
   
}
 //@end ...this is indicator 2
printf("Factorial is %d",fact);
```

Thanks

Comment: "How can I create a parser rule not affect on other rules found in the grammar file?" you can't. Could you explain what you're trying to achieve? Perhaps there's another way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am try to write indicators in the source file (//@start,,//@end) after parsring file by antlr I want to use listener to access the the CTX for these indicator for replace and write before this CTX ..I hope this clear

Comment: Err, yes, that is what you've already explained in your question. My question is why? What are you going to do after that? Please update your question wit that information (don't put that in a comment here please).

Answer (score 1):

Using the grammars just downloaded from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4, called CPP14Lexer.g4 and CPP14Parser.g4. The lexer at line 408

```
LineComment: '//' ~ [\r\n]* -> skip;
```

skips line comments. But lexer rules are greedy : if two rules start with the same character(s), the lexer will choose the one which consumes the most characters. Thus you can add two rules for your needs :

```
Start_indicator : '//@start' ~ [\r\n]* ;
End_indicator   : '//@end'   ~ [\r\n]* ;
LineComment     : '//'       ~ [\r\n]* -> skip;
```

The parser must recognize these tokens, for example with the `indicator` rule added to the `statement` rule (lexer rules start with a capital letter, parser rules with a lower-case) :

```
statement:
    labeledStatement
    | attributeSpecifierSeq? (
        expressionStatement
        | compoundStatement
        | selectionStatement
        | iterationStatement
        | jumpStatement
        | tryBlock
    )
    | declarationStatement
    | indicator
    ;
    
indicator : Start_indicator | End_indicator ;
```

With your example surrounded with a `main` to avoid mistakes, file `t.text`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 for(int i=1;i<=c;i++)
{
    fact=fact*i;
    //@start ...this is indicator 1
   
}
 //@end ...this is indicator 2
printf("Factorial is %d",fact);
}
```

Execution :

```
    $ export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar"
    $ alias a4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar'
    $ alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
    $ a4 CPP*.g4 
    $ javac CPP*.java
    $ grun CPP14 translationUnit -tokens t.text
    [@0,0:2='int',<'int'>,1:0]
    [@1,4:7='main',<Identifier>,1:4]
    ...
    [@28,64:67='fact',<Identifier>,4:4]
    [@29,68:68='=',<'='>,4:8]
    [@30,69:72='fact',<Identifier>,4:9]
    [@31,73:73='*',<'*'>,4:13]
    [@32,74:74='i',<Identifier>,4:14]
    [@33,75:75=';',<';'>,4:15]
    [@34,81:111='//@start ...this is indicator 1',<Start_indicator>,5:4]
    [@35,117:117='}',<'}'>,7:0]
    [@36,120:148='//@end ...this is indicator 2',<End_indicator>,8:1]
    [@37,150:155='printf',<Identifier>,9:0]
    [@38,156:156='(',<'('>,9:6]
    [@39,157:173='"Factorial is %d"',<StringLiteral>,9:7]
    [@40,174:174=',',<','>,9:24]
    [@41,175:178='fact',<Identifier>,9:25]
    [@42,179:179=')',<')'>,9:29]
    [@43,180:180=';',<';'>,9:30]
    [@44,182:182='}',<'}'>,10:0]
    [@45,184:183='<EOF>',<EOF>,11:0]
```

Separate tokens have been produced for `Start_indicator` and `End_indicator`.
The parser rule can be found in the generated `CPP14ParserListener.java` :

```
/**
     * Enter a parse tree produced by {@link CPP14Parser#indicator}.
     * @param ctx the parse tree
     */
    void enterIndicator(CPP14Parser.IndicatorContext ctx);
```

Comment: Thanks @Bernardk for your answer , I still have issue when I implement your approach .when I use rewriter using enterIndicator listener  the modification work ok if the indicator inside loop block or above the  loop but the rewriter can not replace or insert before indicator under the loop

Comment: @AbdulraheemAlofi Maybe you need two distinct parser rules. I have no experience with token stream manipulation. You should ask a question explaining the goal of the transformation and what goes wrong.